# Не могу запушить файлы на github

Tags: github, git-push

День добрый, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Сделал я всё по инструкции, сгенерировал протокол, связал гитхаб и свой пк. Дело вот в чём, когда я ввожу git push -u origin main, долгое время ничего не происходит. Обратите внимание, что я использую не http, а всё таки ssh (выделил). Глобальное имя и емаил я вбил вот скрин: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потом высвечивается данное сообщение, скрин: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Полазил в инте, но всё что нашёл не помогло.

P.S Протестировал ssh коннект комндой "ssh -T git@github.com", выдаёт следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставьте скриншоты в сам вопрос (есть соответствующая кнопка в редакторе вопроса). Еще лучше вставить текстовую информацию текстом.

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Answer (score 0):

У вас не резолвится имя `github.com` - неправильные настройки DNS, файрвол или еще что-то...
Гляньте, что у вас в `/etc/resolv.conf` написано?

Comment: Вот это: # This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.27.96.1